# Need mySQL Function to Scramble Text in a Column

Tags: mysql

I am a newbie to mySQL and PHPmyAdmin - please go easy on me!

I need a function to scramble or replace real data for production/testing purposes (i want to hire a freelancer but need to protect identities first).  I want to scramble their names, their emails, phone numbers, etc., but I need to leave other columns intact (such as state and zip) for our testing purposes.

I have used this:

```
UPDATE members 
SET last_name=REVERSE(last_name);
```

BUT it's too easy to "crack".  Is there a simple but more secure way to scramble the field to protect the privacy?  Maybe a built-in random function? Or even a function to randomly replace characters?

I do not need to "unscramble" data afterwards since this is just a test server anyway.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: use md5 for strings

Comment: you can also use a salt

Comment: Can another person undo md5 encryption if they have access to the PHPmyAdmin?

Comment: No, md5 is one-way. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5.

Comment: Salt is safer than md5. If you want to have a 'reversable' kind of hash, take a look at the MySQL functions AES_ENCRYPT() and AES_DECRYPT() functions (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-encrypt) it works with a predefined key.

Comment: If you are using freelancer for testing, why cannot you provide him with a DB in which all those string are hashed with md5 or something ?

Answer (score 1):

The **Soundex()** function can convert data to a series of letters and number that will be meaningless.